# Firefox must press backspace twice to delete one charecter

Tags: keyboard, firefox

In Firefox in Ubuntu, when I type on some text area and I want to delete an English character I only need to press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> one time, but to delete an Arabic character I have to pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> twice. On some other websites I need to press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> once to delete an Arabic character but twice to delete an English character.

Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem after I upgraded my firefox to version 34 (in ubuntu trusty).
A dirty and quick solution is to downgrade firefox. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/522717/114243) to downgrade firefox from version 34 to 28 and now the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report on Launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1405930

Comment: Please say that as a comment not an answer...

Comment: I am not privileged to do that because of not having enough reputations.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you should open the about:config page and change the value of `bidi.edit.delete_immediately` key from **false** to **true**.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox 109.0.1, as of 11 Feb 2023, the bug is back, and the fix now seems to require that `editor.word_select.delete_space_after_doubleclick_selection` *also* be set to `true`... at least it works on this PC. Thanks to Ravexina for pointing me in the right direction.

BTW, this issue is also present in the Windows version of Firefox, and it *also* inhibits <kbd>Back Space</kbd> **repeat**. *sigh*