# How to install previous Firefox version?

Tags: firefox, downgrade, firefox-extensions

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I use the Perapera Chinese add-on for Firefox. It worked up to version 39, but now in version 40 it just stopped working. So I tried to downgrade to version 39 following [this link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox), where there are two options:

1) Choose from the list [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/), but I have no idea which of the 11 subversions should I use.

2) Download the only version suggested in the link above, i.e. [this](https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/39.0.3/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-39.0.3.tar.bz2).

I chose the 2nd option, but after decompressing the file, I have a 'Firefox' folder with lots of files and executables that don't run, just give an error message:

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file (...)/firefox/libxul.so:
libXcomposite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

There's a 'run-mozilla.sh', but 'bash run-mozilla.sh' gives:

```
run-mozilla.sh: Cannot execute .
```

I REALLY would like to use Perapera add-on to study Chinese. So, is there an easy way to downgrade to Firefox 39? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### You may have two choice to choose for installing method:

1. Via [Mozilla's ftp site](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) (kudos for @Bhikku for sharing the link !). For example we're going to install firefox 50. First, remove any existing version.

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge firefox
   ```

   Then run following command to download firefox 50 source code, which comes as `.tar` file.

   ```
   wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/50.0/linux-$(uname -m)/en-US/firefox-50.0.tar.bz2
   ```

   Extract the package.

   ```
   tar -xjf firefox-50.0.tar.bz2
   ```

   Move firefox to `/opt` directory.

   ```
   sudo mv firefox /opt/
   ```

   Create symlink in order to set the new firefox as default.

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox_old
   sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
   ```
2. Via [UbuntuZilla](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/) which offer `.deb` files, to install follow the instruction below.

---

Remove firefox first :

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

Run following command to download firefox :

32 Bit

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/firefox-mozilla-build_39.0.3-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

64 Bit

```
wget sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntuzilla/files/mozilla/apt/pool/main/f/firefox-mozilla-build/firefox-mozilla-build_39.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Install it :

32 Bit

```
cd Downloads/ && sudo dpkg -i firefox-mozilla-build_39.0.3-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

64 Bit

```
cd Downloads/ && sudo dpkg -i firefox-mozilla-build_39.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

And firefox should run the 39 version

Quote from ubuntuzilla official wiki page :

> This is the home of the Ubuntuzilla project, hosts an APT repository with .deb **repacks of the latest official release versions of Mozilla Firefox**, Mozilla SeaMonkey, and Mozilla Thunderbird.

Comment: Thanks, Liso, it worked. But isn't it a bit strange that this package should reside in 'ubuntuzilla' @ sf.net? I mean, why can't it be @ mozilla.org? How can I be sure that ubuntuzilla is made by the same guys at mozilla, and not by some hackers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure ubuntuzilla is trusted, since the author just repack the official release by mozilla.

Comment: If the work is "just repack", then it's still amazing that Mozilla can't do that themselves...

Comment: http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti Thank you! That feels much safer!

Comment: @Rodrigo You can also get deb packages from the publishing history in Mozilla's official Firefox launchpad repository: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+publishinghistory

Comment: Too bad damn thing automatically updates itself from 59 to 71 on second starup...

Answer (score 21):

In a terminal run:

```
apt-cache show firefox | grep Version
```

You will get a list of available versions like in the list below:

```
Version: 54.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Version: 45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
```

Install the desired version with:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox=45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
```

Prevent Ubuntu from upgrading to the latest version:

```
sudo apt-mark hold firefox
```

Comment: apt-cache show firefox;
N: Can't select versions from package 'firefox' as it is purely virtual;
N: No packages found

Comment: This is my preferred method, because it lets me still using the package manager and I plan to use it to go back to the latest version someday soon. Ver. 45 is early enough for us to use with Selenium 2, which is why I'm here.

Comment: That's definitely the answer I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

While the normal repository often only contains the latest version for older Ubuntu releases, you may be able to find the previous version with the help of Google.

Generalizing from [this blog about Firefox 43 on Ubuntu 12.04](http://bahut.alma.ch/2015/12/firefox-43-crashes-install-previous.html), you could search for

https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+$FF_VERSION+$UBUNTU_VERSION+deb

Then

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
wget "$URL"
sudo dpkg -i "firefox-....deb"
sudo apt-mark hold firefox
```

The drawback is that you won't get security upgrades for Firefox, so this is only a temporary solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to test your solution, just because I solved it a while ago. But thanks for you trying (and helping who gets here in the future).

Comment: thanks for the apt-mark tip, was getting tired of refusing updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I downgraded to Firefox 50 version from version 57.

1. Go to [Firefox Release](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) archive and download a suitable version for you.
2. Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` to open the terminal and copy-paste this code:

   ```
   sudo apt remove firefox
   ```

   To uninstall Firefox current version.
3. Now, go to the directory where Firefox-.tar.gz( or .tar.gz2) file is kept using the terminal or using file manager. Enter this code( if using the terminal):

   ```
   tar -xzf firefox-.tar.gz2
   ```

   If using file manager, simply extract the file using the Archive Manager(Look in the context menu).
4. Open the folder and run the file 'firefox'.

**Caution:** Don't forget to stop automatic updates in Firefox.

This is the way I did it. Firefox is not installed completely but it still works the way it should. Only the options and the Firefox symbol are not there.

I recommend locking the Firefox in the launcher.

To create a shortcut on the desktop, go to the file and open context menu. Click on 'Make Link'. The file created is to be pasted on the desktop.

Hope this helps!:)