# Downgrade Firefox on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: 14.04, firefox, mate, xrdp

Firefox 50 on Ubuntu Mate via xrdp renders wrong colors due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1643871).

When I try to uninstall Firefox 50 and install 49 as described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/661193/26022) usin `sudo apt-get purge firefox`, I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox* ubuntu-mate-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 113 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Does this meaning that continuing with the command, it will uninistall my Mate desktop as well?

Can I avoid that?

Comment: It'll uninstall the meta-package only. But even so why don't you try upgrading to the Dev edition instead of downgrading? It should be fixed by now.

Comment: Installed Developer edition now but it crashes constantly when being started.