# Firefox uses a different keyboard layout on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: firefox, keyboard-layout

Using Mozilla Firefox 68.0.1 on Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64 on a Dell G3 3579.

Using keyboard layout `International (AltGr dead keys)`. The keyboard works as expected in the terminal or gedit, but for some reason, on Firefox, it doesn't. Pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> doesn't create a dead key but just produces a `'`.

Comment: Please go to _Settings -> Region & Language_ and click the _Input Sources_ gearwheel icon. Is the option "Use the same source for all windows" selected?

Comment: Maybe im-config related. `im-config -m` please.

Comment: Does or Chromium or Chrome do the same thing? Does an older version of Firefox do the same thing? Does installing a different kernel version do the same thing? I'm wondering if we can narrow it down somehow...

Comment: I have the exactly same issue after upgrade from debian stretch to buster.
All the gnome's app works correctly, but firefox, chrome or slack don't...

Comment: I finally fix the issue using:

`setxkbmap -rules evdev -model pc105 -layout us -variant altgr-intl`

Comment: I still have this issue. I can type `\`` but Firefox from the Ubuntu package fails French accents that require a combination of keys like `ê` and `ï`. However dead keys work on other programs like Thunderbird or Firefox binary from Mozilla. Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1924586

Answer (score 0):

Terminal and Gedit are Gnome products but FireFox is not. You could try the Unity Desktop:

- [How to Switch from GNOME to Unity in Ubuntu 18.04 and 17.10](https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/)

Although written for 17.10 and 18.04 the same installation techniques apply with 19.04.

For a different set of screenshots with Ubuntu 19.04 installation of Unity see:

- [Unity Desktop on Ubuntu 19.04](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2019/05/unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-1904.html)

The only other thing I can think of trying is a different version of Firefox but I'm not sure how successful this would be:

- [How to install previous Firefox version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661186/how-to-install-previous-firefox-version)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way seams to put the call `setxkbmap [lang]`, where lang = de, en etc. to `/etc/profile` or any other configuration file, read for all users.