# How to install firefoxdriver webdriver for python3 selenium on ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, python3

I installed python3-selenium apt package on Ubuntu 16.04. While installing, got a message:

```
Suggested packages:
chromedriver firefoxdriver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
python3-selenium
```

When I try to run the following python code,

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.5
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def get_profile():
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", True)
    return profile

def main():
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=getProfile())

    #browser shall call the URL
    browser.get("http://www.google.com")
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./test.py", line 19, in <module>
        main()
    File "./test.py", line 11, in main
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=getProfile())
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox      /webdriver.py", line 77, in __init__
self.binary, timeout),
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
self.profile.add_extension()
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 91, in add_extension
self._install_extension(extension)
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py", line 251, in _install_extension
compressed_file = zipfile.ZipFile(addon, 'r')
   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 1009, in __init__
self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib /firefoxdriver/webdriver.xpi'
```

I did searching for packages name firefoxdriver in Ubuntu repositories but none exist.

Any help with installing the webdrivers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [latest geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.11.1), then untar the file and put it in your path (i.e. `~/.local/bin`).

This will solve the exception but your program will be hanging after this line :

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=getProfile())
```

The only solution I found is to [downgrade Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/a/522717/502491).

First, list the available versions :

```
apt-cache policy firefox
```

Then install a version lower than 49 (`45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1` for me) :

```
sudo apt install firefox=45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1
```

You could use chromium instead ...